# Is it possible to generate strings of text that follow a pattern

Tags: php

I would like to create a website that allows a user to generate a selectable number of unique strings of text that all follow an algorithm but as it is website based I am not too sure about how I go about it.

For example user A wants to generate 20 strings of unique text that all follow say AA***B^^** where A&B is a constant that doesn't change, where * is a random number and ^ is a random letter.

Is that possible? I am thinking of using php rand for the number but not 100% sure.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is, carry on.

Comment: How to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fine. Can you give me a starting point? There's no need to be rude

Comment: rude is not reading the S.O help center topic on how to ask, before asking. I can think of 6 dozen approaches to this question, I would start by defining how the user will provide the pattern.

Comment: I forgot to include something, shoot me. If every pattern is different but all follow the uniform * for a number and ^ for a letter then I'm guessing an input box

Comment: mind your attitude when asking for *free* help. I would use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to solve this myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php

function randomGenerator($string)
{
    $string_array = str_split( $string );

    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    foreach ($string_array as $k => $v) {
        if ($v == '*')
            $string_array[$k] = rand(0,9);
        if ($v == '^')
            $string_array[$k] = $characters[rand(0,51)];
    }

    $string = implode('', $string_array);


    return $string;
}

echo randomGenerator('AA***NN^^'); // may print AA478NNhU
```